# Cast child as far parent and then as direct child c#

Tags: c#, casting, parent-child

I can’t cast parent class as a child – keep getting Invalid Cast Exception.

I can’t overcome this problem and I would rally use some help.

I’m developing an application that creates certain documents. There are total of 20 documents. 19 of themare unique and one derives from a different one by extending it contents. All certificates have common header information and document-specific body.

So I created `Document` class. I never instantiate `Document` class directly, only through its children. 19 documents are directly derived from `Document` class. `Document` class defines all fields and properties common to all documents along with methods to access SQL database. Constructors of each `Document` (child), when initiated to no argument call `Document`’s (parent) constructor passing an integer that helps that constructor select some unique information from common database table, such as unique title of the document, disclaimer or footer note.

Each document is to be created with Win Form interface. I created base interface that is common to all certificates and operates on header information as well as it contains methods common to all `Document`-*WindowsForm* interactions. Each child document has own form that derives from that parent form. On initialization each form instantiates corresponding `Document` (child) class and displays document title, disclaimer and footnote on load. Since documents rely on header info from the base form all methods are defined inside base form. Those methods accept and return `Document` data type (parent) because I never know what form will call them. Each time I pass newly instantiated Document as Document class (parent) and I cast returned datatype to match what I needed. That way I retain unique properties od child `Documents` while using generic methods to collect common information. That works for 19 of 20 documents. 20th is a problem. `Doc20` derives from `Doc19` which derives from `Document` class. Likewise `Form20` derives from `Form19` which derives from `GenericForm`. `Doc20` is in fact a significant extension of `Doc19`.

On form `Init` I instantiate new `Doc20` object. I grab title, disclaimer and footnote on form load event and display it as needed.

Then I try to call a method in `GenericForm` that accepts and returns Document class and cast a return value as `Doc20`. That works.

Next I call method in `Form19`. That method also accepts `Document` class and returns `Document` class and is tasked with collecting data from controls common to `Form19` and `Form20`. I pass my `Doc20` object as Document. Inside this method I need to access properties specific to `Doc19` (thus `Doc20`) so I try to cast is as `Doc19` and this is where Exception gets thrown. Interestingly Intelisense has no problems with syntax and application compiles just fine. Any idea why I cant cast parent as a child?

Comment: All that prose, but no code.  Please post your code.

Comment: Maybe because your "child" doesn't _inherit_ from the "parent"?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm just impressed you read the whole thing.

Comment: @Jonesy barely. I skimmed most of it.